# echo items from header response in php

Tags: php, header

I want to echo items from this header response separately.

```
 $headers = get_headers('https://businesspeopleclub.com/demo-files/Sample-Zip-file.zip', TRUE);
```

This is the respond in array

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Date] => Tue, 26 May 2020 02:23:04 GMT
    [Server] => Apache
    [Last-Modified] => Sun, 27 Jan 2019 21:02:55 GMT
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
    [Content-Length] => 8851
    [Vary] => Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
    [Connection] => close
    [Content-Type] => application/zip
)
```

Example - I want to echo file size but it does not display.

```
$filesize = $headers['content-length'];

echo$filesize;
```

Comment: keys in associative array in php are case sensitive, try `$headers['Content-Length']`

Comment: Hi catcon ! You are right. It is case sensitive. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pay attention to the letter case.

```
$headers['Content-Length']; !== $headers['content-length']; //true
'Content-Length' !== 'content-length'; //true
```

Code you want to run is:

```
$filesize = $headers['Content-Length'];

echo$filesize;
```

Comment: Hi Tajni. Its case sensitive. Thank you !